# Regex - Convert pattern from php to Java

Tags: java, regex

In **php** I can check if a word is in a String like that

```
$muster = "/\b($word)\b/i";
if(preg_match($muster, $text)) {
        return true;
}
```

**Example:**

```
$word = "test";
$text = "This is a :::test!!!";
```

Returns **true**

---

I tried converting this into **Java**:

```
if (Pattern.matches("(?i)\\b(" + word + ")\\b", text)) {
   return true;
}
```

The same **example** :

```
String word = "test";
String text = "This is a :::test!!!";
```

would return **false**

---

What am I missing here? :(

Comment: `Pattern.matches("(?i).*\\b" + word + "\\b.*"` as `matches` means match complete input in Java.

Comment: You can use indexOf to see if string contains a specific word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and call [find](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) like this :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b(" + word + ")\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
System.out.println(matcher.find());// true if match false if not
```